# Сравнить слова (лексемы) вводимого текста со словами из текстового файла

Tags: c++, linux

Надо сравнить лексемы вводимого текста с лексемами из текстового файла и выводить  следующую строку от найденной лексемы. Но не удаётся вывести. Почему?

Пробую так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    string word;
    char buffer[200];
    //----------------Работа с вводимым текстом-------------------------------
    getline(cin, text);
    stringstream buff(text);
    vector <string> vectext;
    while(buff >> word) vectext.push_back(word);
    //unsigned int vector_size = vectext.size(); 
    //--------------------------Работа с текстовым файлом---------------------
    ifstream fin("text.txt");
     if (!fin.is_open()) 
            cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
        }
       while (fin >> word) 
        for (int i = 0; i < vectext.size(); i++) 
            if (word == vectext[i]) 
            { 
            getline(fin,word);// не выводит, а если через fin >> word, то работает.
            cout << word << endl;
            break;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: Лексемой вы называете любую последовательность "непробельных" символов?

Comment: @avp, Да. Лексема - это слово.

Comment: Что вам мешает точно так же, как вы считывали слова входного текста в `word` и запоминали их в `vectext`,  считывать  слова из файла в цикле  в тот же `word` и искать этот `word` в `vectext`?

Comment: @avp, Вы имеете ввиду циклом  передавать  каждую лексему из файла , записывая в word?  Я пробовал так, только  с помощью отдельной переменной, но  не удалось.Но, мне кажется из за неправильной логики работы цикла.

Comment: @Alex, пишите свои варианты кода (лучше с отладочной печатью) и задавайте конкретные вопросы в виде -- `"вот тут я ожидаю такие значения переменных, в они вот такие, в чем ошибка?"` (вы же всерьез не ждете, что кто-то напишет все за вас?)

Comment: @avp, нет, я не жду пока мне кто-то сделает всё, каков тогда смысл обучения. А насчет, правильного оформления, извините , учту. Вот как я пытался делать. Компилирует, но не делает свой функционал. Если расширить суть моей задачи, то мне надо найти эту лексему в файле и если есть, то вывести следующую строку текстового файла.                `ifstream fin("text.txt");
if (!fin.is_open()) 
       cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
while (!fin.eof())
{
 fin >> word;
 for (int i = 0; i < vectext.size(); ++i)  
 {
  if(vectext[i]== buffer)
  cout <<"Work" << endl; 
 }
}`

Comment: Я думаю, что дело в цикле. Не так ли?

Comment: Да. Я вообще в тексте программы в вопросе не вижу чтения файла `fin`. Если см. на прогу в вашем комментарии, то вы читаете в `word`, а в цикле поиска сравниваете с `buffer` (понятно, что не сработает). Кроме того, условие `eof()` возникает **после чтения** (`while (!fin.eof())` ... так неправильно)

Comment: Ой, извините. Насчёт,чтения файла , то fin >> word, это  передача  
"непробельными" символами.

Comment: Исправил, находит, но почему-то  теперь бесконечный цикл. Как я понимаю,это из за неправильного условия цикла?

Comment: А нет, в любом случае выдаёт "work" , и бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @Alex, отредактируйте, наконец, текст кода в вопросе, чтобы можно было видеть актуальную версию. Код цикла ввода для поиска напишите просто -- `while (fin >> word) for (int i = 0; i < vectext.size(); i++) if (word == vectext[i]) { cout << word << " found\n"; break;}` Должно работать. Потом правьте/улучшайте под свою задачу

Comment: @avp, Исправил, извините, изначально не понял о чём вы имели ввиду. Насчёт задачки,  работает. Но есть вопрос, как можно реализовать вывод следующей строки?

Comment: @avp,Но есть вопрос, как можно реализовать вывод следующей строки? Допустим в `cout`  мне  выводило следующую строку, находящего лексема. Для этого мне надо делать подсчёт строк?

Comment: @Alex, что-то я перестал понимать вашу задачу (не слишком тщательно анализировал несколько сбивчивое рассуждение о строках и буфере). Попробую сформулировать. После заполнения вектора словами вы ищете их в файле. Файл надо читать построчно. Если в прочитанной **строке** есть хотя бы одно слово, то требуется вывести  следующую строку?  (в ней тоже нужно искать слова?) Попробуйте доходчиво сформулировать саму задачу, лучше прямо в тексте вопроса (кстати, замечание о подсчете строк я тоже не понял).

Comment: @avp, извините, постараюсь уточнить. Задача заключается в этом: пользователь вводит текст. Этот текст разбивается на лексемы ( слова) , после этого, происходит поиск этих слов в текстовом файле. В текстовом  файле содержится: Одна строка - лексема , вторая - это строка для вывода.  Если лексема присутствует , то выводится это "предложение".

Comment: @avp, насчет подсчет строк, это просто предположение. Я просто  особо практического опыта  не имею насчет этого.

Comment: Ага, теперь понятною Подсчет строк и вывод их номеров это на ваше усмотрение (подозреваю, что это все равно какое-то домашнее задание, с препом разберетесь). А что теперь-то, когда вы все нормально написали словами вам не понятно? Файл в цикле читаете по строкам `while(getline(fin, text)) { ...`. Считываете из строки первое слово в `word`, читаете следующую строку (причем проверяете, что она существует, т.е. пишете `if (getline(fin, text)) { ...`), ее и будете печатать если найдете `word` в `vectext`. //// Вроде все. Желаю удачи

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: @avp, с праздником, и извините за наглость, но можете ли вы мне обьяснить, почему таким способом не получается вывести следующую строку. (Код в правке)

Comment: @Alex, спасибо! Вас тоже, с уже прошедшим -). `getline(file, str)` читает любой текст (включая пробелы и т.п.) до  `\n` в `str` (`\n` она "проглатывает"). А операция `>>` читает следующее "слово" (т.е. последовательность непробельных символов), пропуская все пробелы, табуляции, `\n` и  т.п. перед словом. Т.о. когда вы читаете `word`, и находите его в списке, то следующая `getline(fin,word);` читает остаток  строки (реально там скорее всего пусто). Я бы посоветовал не смешивать `>>` и `getline` для одного и того же источника данных (файла) и в вашей задаче всюду читать через `getline`

Comment: @Alex, ну как у вас, все получилось?

Comment: @avp, здравствуйте,  не совсем понимаю, как это должно работать через getline.

Comment: @avp, извините, что  долгий период не отвечал. Другие факторы не давали время  к саморазвитию .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что мне проще объяснить, написав работающий код на основе вашего (насколько я понял все условия (в т.ч. озвученные в комментариях)).

Итак, программа вводит строку содержащую список поисковых слов (лексем, в вашей терминологии).
Затем она читает файл  вот в таком формате:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat text.txt
b1 aa
line 1 text...
b2 
line 2 text... word1 word2 word3
b3 bbb
line 3 text...
b4
line 4 word1 word2 word3
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Четные строки файла содержат список лексем, "адресующих" следующую строку.

Программа должна напечатать те строки (вместе с их порядковыми номерами) этого файла, для которых хотя бы одна из лексем, введенных со стандартного ввода совпала хотя бы с одной из "адресующих" строку лексем.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  string text;
  string word;
  char buffer[200];
  //----------------Работа с вводимым текстом-------------------------------
  getline(cin, text);
  stringstream buff(text);
  vector <string> vectext;
  while (buff >> word)
    vectext.push_back(word);


  //--------------------------Работа с текстовым файлом---------------------
  ifstream fin(av[1] ? av[1] : "text.txt");
  if (!fin.is_open()) 
    cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n", exit(1);

  int lineno = 0;
  while (getline(fin, text)) { // читаем строку лексем
    lineno++;
    string text2;
    if (getline(fin, text2)) { // читаем следующую строку, с которой связаны лексемы
      lineno++;
      stringstream lwords(text);
      bool found = false;

      while (!found && lwords >> word) // перебираем лексемы связанные со строкой
        for (int i = 0; !found && i < vectext.size(); i++)
          if (vectext[i] == word) { // сравниваем с лексемами в введенном тексте
            found = true;
            cout << lineno << ": " << text2 << '\n';
            cout << "found by '" << word << "'\n\n";
          }     
    } else
      cout << "error in file format\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Пример запуска:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ t.cpp && ./a.out
bbb b1 b2
2: line 1 text...
found by 'b1'

4: line 2 text... word1 word2 word3
found by 'b2'

6: line 3 text...
found by 'bbb'

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Если что-то неясно, спрашивайте.

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое,  довольно понятно всё. Я теперь понимаю, что вы имели ввиду, только есть вопрос, почему если в текстовом документе будут русские лексемы, то не работает? А так, то что не понятно, я разобрался, только вот мне интересно  эта часть кода  `av[1] ? av[1] : "text.txt"`, просто раньше такого не видел.

Comment: @Alex,   у меня  Linux с локалями в utf-8 и поиск с русскими лексемами работает. Код `av[1] ? av[1] : "text.txt"` (это так называемый *тернарный оператор*) смотрит, если программа запущена с аргументом командной строки, то использует его как имя файла в котором ищем, а если без аргуменов, то берет файл по умолчанию -- text.txt

Comment: @avp, понял, спасибо большое. Насчет  поиск русских лексем, попробую разобраться. Ещё раз, спасибо.

Comment: @Alex, OK/ Главное, сами побольше пишите. Если что-то не получается, спрашивайте (только учтите, хороший вопрос должен содержать минимальный законченный код,  описание формата данных (или последовательность действий) с примером и описание что ожидали увидеть, а что реально видите)